# Styling HTML newsletter

Tags: html, css, newsletter

HTML newsletters. Sometimes quite the view to look at, but at the moment it looks more like a coding nightmare to me. I'm used to separate html and css but when writing an HTML newsletter, this isn't really an option (or is it?)

So what is the best-practice to style an html newsletter? Put all the css in a single `<style>` tag on top of the code? Style every single element on its own with the style property? Or mess around with table widths enough to make it look right? Perhaps a bit of everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are a coding nightmare. Avoid the style-Tag (some Webmail clients strip them out anyway), go easy on inline-styles (not everything works in every mail client - best you limit yourself to some basic typo), avoid background-images (as they do not work consistently and sometimes not at all), use lots of nested tables (but try and do not chop up images to place the parts in adjacent table cells, since some mail clients might introduce gaps between table cells) and most importantly, test your templates with every major mail client (testing them in the browser as HTML pages is next to useless since many mail clients makes changes to the code before displaying it). And test them with exact the same programm you'll use to send the real newsletter, since some programm introduce code changes on sending.

The best suggestions I can make from painful experience are a) keep it simple, b) buy a tested newsletter template and adapt it carefully to your needs and c) don't send HTML newsletters.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll keep suggestion c) in mind :p

Answer (score 1):

Email design and development it's one of the worst things there is. Mostly because so different approach in rendering and parsing by different clients. Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook all having their own 'say'. You would have to combine styles set in `<style>` but also put some inline styling as well, for example for table width or cells.

It's gonna take a lot of time before you'll learn what to use and how, it takes dozens of e-mails.

One thing I can advise is to use automated tool to check your e-mails like [Litmus](http://litmus.com/).

Additionally have a read about which tags or styles are not liked by particular email clients. For that I would recommend [CampaignMonitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: That CampaignMonitor link looks helpful, thanks.

Comment: Also sometimes `<style>` tags can be removed, as well as everything in `<head>` that's why it's good to have a fail safe in html inline styling.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML newsletters keep your css as inline and use "TABLES" some email clients don't support DIV'S like MS Outlook..

Comment: Didn't know that about the divs, thanks.

Comment: full samples codes?